# Can S3 bucket be slowed down by Internet Provider?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket in us-east-2 region and access is mainly from Nepal. When I use my Wifi, it is really slow  but when using mobile data it is fast enough. And it is also fast when using VPN outside my country. What could be the reason behind it. Also the speed was good enough just a day before. Just today it started to slow down for no reason. Is it due to my Wifi provider? What should I do in this situation?

Comment: Are you using your S3 bucket to store some objects/files, to host a static website or for other purpose? Also, how much data are you transfering (GB, TB)?

Comment: I am using it for static files and also for some uploads. The data transfer is very small 100 Kb takes 4-5 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buckets are globally accessible, but they reside in a specific AWS Region. The geographical distance between the request and the bucket contributes to the time it takes for a response to be received.

To decrease the distance between the client and the S3 bucket, consider moving your data into a bucket in another Region that's closer to the client. You can configure [cross-Region replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html#crr-scenario) so that data in the source bucket is replicated into the destination bucket in the new Region. As another option, consider migrating the client closer to the S3 bucket.

You can also try [S3 Transfer Acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/s3-optimizing-performance-best-practices/use-amazon-s3-transfer-acceleration-to-minimize-latency-caused-by-distance.html), which manages fast, easy, and secure transfers of files over long geographic distances between the client and an S3 bucket. It takes advantage of the globally distributed edge locations in [Amazon CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/?whats-new-cloudfront.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cloudfront.sort-order=desc). As the data arrives at an edge location, it is routed to Amazon S3 over an optimized network path. Transfer Acceleration is ideal for transferring gigabytes to terabytes of data regularly across continents. It's also useful for clients that upload to a centralized bucket from all over the world.

> Can S3 bucket be slowed down by Internet Provider?

If you are connecting to S3 over the Internet, the performance of your your Internet connection can affect S3 upload and download time. Because of the difference in the network latency between WiFi and Mobile network, I encourage you to test whether the cause of your issues is with your network rather than with your AWS setup. Here is a robust guideline on [how to troubleshoot slow or inconsistent speeds when downloading or uploading to Amazon S3](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-slow-downloads-uploads).

Comment: Thanks man. I finally tested another s3 bucket located in India and the speed seems to be fine from there. I guess I should move to there now.